# Pandas merging/joining tables with multiple key columns and duplicating rows where necessary

Tags: python, pandas

I have several tables that contain lab results, with a 'master' table of sample data with things like a description. The results tables are also broken down by specimen (sub-samples). They contain multiple results columns - I'm just showing one here. I want to combine all the results tables into one dataframe, like this:

```
Table 1:
Location    Sample   Description
1           A        Yellow
1           B        Red
2           A        Blue
2           B        Violet

Table 2
Location  Sample    Specimen   Result1
1         A         X          5
1         A         Y          6
1         B         X          10
2         A         X          1

Table 3
Location  Sample    Specimen   Result2
1         A         X          "Heavy"
1         A         Q          "Soft"
1         B         K          "Grey"
2         B         Z          "Bananas"

Desired Output:
Location  Sample  Description  Specimen  Result1  Result2
1         A       Yellow       X         5        "Heavy"
1         A       Yellow       Y         6        nan
1         A       Yellow       Q         nan      "Soft"
1         B       Red          X         10       nan
1         B       Red          K         nan      "Grey"
2         A       Blue         X         1        nan
2         B       Violet       Z         nan      "Bananas"
```

I currently have a solution for this using `iterrows()` and `df.append()`, but these are both slow operations and when there are thousands of results it takes too long. Is there better way? I have tried using `join()` and `merge()` but I can't seem to get the result I want.

Quick code to reproduce my dataframes:

```py
dict1 = {'Location': [1,1,2,2], 'Sample': ['A','B','A','B'], 'Description': ['Yellow','Red','Blue','Violet']}
dict2 = {'Location': [1,1,1,2], 'Sample': ['A','A','B','A'], 'Specimen': ['x', 'y','x', 'x'], 'Result1': [5,6,10,1]}
dict3 = {'Location': [1,1,1,2], 'Sample': ['A','A','B','B'], 'Specimen': ['x', 'q','k', 'z'], 'Result2': ["Heavy","Soft","Grey","Bananas"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is join `df2, df3` together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and for unique `'Location','Sample','Specimen'` rows are rows aggregated by `sum`, last merge to `df1`:

```
df23 = (pd.concat([df2, df3])
          .groupby(['Location','Sample','Specimen'], as_index=False, sort=False)
          .sum(min_count=1))
df = df1.merge(df23, on=['Location','Sample'])
print (df)
   Location Sample Description Specimen  Result1  Result2
0         1      A      Yellow        x      5.0      4.0
1         1      A      Yellow        y      6.0      NaN
2         1      A      Yellow        q      NaN      6.0
3         1      B         Red        x     10.0      NaN
4         1      B         Red        k      NaN      8.0
5         2      A        Blue        x      1.0      NaN
6         2      B      Violet        z      NaN      5.0
```

Or if all rows in `df2,df3` per columns `['Location','Sample','Specimen']` are unique, solution is simplier:

```
df23 = pd.concat([df2.set_index(['Location','Sample','Specimen']), 
                  df3.set_index(['Location','Sample','Specimen'])], axis=1)

df = df1.merge(df23.reset_index(), on=['Location','Sample'])
print (df)
   Location Sample Description Specimen  Result1  Result2
0         1      A      Yellow        q      NaN      6.0
1         1      A      Yellow        x      5.0      4.0
2         1      A      Yellow        y      6.0      NaN
3         1      B         Red        k      NaN      8.0
4         1      B         Red        x     10.0      NaN
5         2      A        Blue        x      1.0      NaN
6         2      B      Violet        z      NaN      5.0
```

EDIT: With new data second solution working well:

```
df23 = pd.concat([df2.set_index(['Location','Sample','Specimen']), 
                  df3.set_index(['Location','Sample','Specimen'])], axis=1)

df = df1.merge(df23.reset_index(), on=['Location','Sample'])
print (df)        
   Location Sample Description Specimen  Result1  Result2
0         1      A      Yellow        q      NaN     Soft
1         1      A      Yellow        x      5.0    Heavy
2         1      A      Yellow        y      6.0      NaN
3         1      B         Red        k      NaN     Grey
4         1      B         Red        x     10.0      NaN
5         2      A        Blue        x      1.0      NaN
6         2      B      Violet        z      NaN  Bananas
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks for the answer. I'm trying your solution 1 which is working except in step 1, some columns are being dropped completely. The results dataframes contain various unique columns and some are being kept in the new df and some aren't, and I can't see a reason for it or a pattern in which ones are being dropped.

Comment: @Alex - they are removed, because not numeric. `groupby.sum` return numeric columns + columns used for grouping, here `['Location','Sample','Specimen']`.

Comment: Understood, and you're correct it's the non-numeric columns that are being dropped. Well the problem is that I need some of those non-numeric columns - I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Alex - For me working well second solution, added to answer.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea you could index off a list of columns, effectively creating a unique ID. Fantastic. Accepting this answer!